# How to pop UIViewController from UIView?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

From the rootViewController,I swipe out an 320x50 sized UIView with two buttons.

When clicked on the button in UIView,how to pop an UIViewController?

Thanks.

Comment: I have solved this in another way.When clicked on the button in UIView,I post a notification to rootViewController use NSNotificationCenter.Then let the rootViewController to pop another UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

> // Create a Navigation controller

```
 UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
     initWithRootViewController:viewController];

 // show the navigation controller modally
 [youCurrentNavigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```